# Counting keys in the JSON

Tags: json

This is my json

```
    var json = {
    "pages": [{
        "name": "page1",
        "elements": [{
                "type": "text",
                "name": "question1"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "question2"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "question3"
            }
        ]
    }]
};
```

Now I try to count this json with this code

```
var keyCount  = Object.keys(json).length;

console.log(keyCount);
```

The output is 1.

But all i need is count this

- {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "question1",
     },
- {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "question2",
     },
- {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "question3",
     }

It's should be 3.
Can someone help me?

```
  var json = {
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page1",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "question1",
    },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "question2",
    },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "question3",
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "page2",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "question4"
    },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "question5"
    },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "question6"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Now I has another question.

You will see the "name": "page1" now it's has a page1, page2

and when i count page it return me just 3.

Why the return of this not 6

```
 var count = json.pages[0].elements.length
    console.log(count);
```

6 is from

- { "type": "text", "name": "question1", },
- { "type": "text", "name": "question2", },
- { "type": "text", "name": "question3", }
  question1-3 from page1)
- { "type": "text", "name": "question4", },
- { "type": "text", "name": "question5", },
- { "type": "text", "name": "question6", }
  (question4-6 from page2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because you have only one key : `page`. Also, pages is an array, so you should access the first cell.

Try counting inside it :

`var count = json.pages[0].elements.length`

I'd recommend using [Jsoneditoronline](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) for viewing easily JSON structures.

Comment: hey a has another question can you help me?

Comment: If it's linked to this question yes. Else, please search if your question hasn't been answered already on this site, or post a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to count the number of elements under the `elements` attribute. So you should do

`var keyCount  = Object.keys(json.pages[0].elements).length;`

Also `elements` is an array so

`var keyCount  = json.pages[0].elements.length`

will work too.